# How to set the image for each segment in UIsegment Control

Tags: iphone

Iam developing one application.In that i need to set the image for segments in the segment control.So please tell me how to do that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use         `[segmentedControl setImage: forSegmentAtIndex: ];`  method

Comment: OK.How to set the frame size differently for each segment.

Comment: you cant give different frame for each segment, you can give frame for whole segment control

Answer (score 0):

jus set an image for the index

```
[segmentedC setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your image"] forSegmentAtIndex:1];
```