# Giving image to uibutton in program

Tags: objective-c

I have a set of `UIButton`s and I gave them images manually. But I'm using a segmented control. So that the images should change according to the selected segment index. I have only little knowledge in objective-c.

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set the image for each segment in UIsegment Control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278619/how-to-set-the-image-for-each-segment-in-uisegment-control)

Comment: [Buttonname setimage:[uiimage imagenamed: @"image1.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line:

```
[yourbuttonobject setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[yourbuttonobject setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: What is [yourbuttonobject]? Is that the button name?

Comment: Thank you soo much. I know there is action for those buttons. I'm little confused with storing image into some object (string or array) with the ibaction.

Comment: can you explain your problem? i think this problem not belongs to this

Comment: I have a segmented control with two segments. When i select one segment, some images will have to display and on clicking on an image that image has to be stored.